# Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Readonly<Record<string, unknown> & InjectedAuthRouterProps<(...args: any[]) => Action>>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-hoc

I am trying to integrate [redux-auth-wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-auth-wrapper) in a typescript based React project. However, I am getting an error when I am trying to use the auth HOC wrapped component anywhere. I thought the auth related props would be injected by the auth HOC but it's asking me to provide them.

Error

```
Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Readonly<Record<string,
unknown> & InjectedAuthRouterProps<(...args: any[]) => Action>>': redirect,
redirectPath, isAuthenticated, isAuthenticating
```

The error happens in my Routes file when I try to use the SubServiceOverview component which is wrapped using the HOC. Files are given below.

reduxAuth.ts

```
import { routerActions } from "connected-react-router";
import { AuthWrapperDecorator } from "redux-auth-wrapper";
import {
  connectedRouterRedirect,
  InjectedAuthRouterProps
} from "redux-auth-wrapper/history4/redirect";

import { RootState } from "state/configureStore";
import { REDUCER_NAME } from "state/user/constants";

const authenticatedSelector = (state: RootState) =>
  state[REDUCER_NAME] && state[REDUCER_NAME]["authenticated"];

export const makeUserIsAuthenticated = <
  OwnProps = Record<string, unknown>
>(): AuthWrapperDecorator<OwnProps & InjectedAuthRouterProps> =>
  connectedRouterRedirect<OwnProps, RootState>({
    redirectPath: "/login",
    authenticatedSelector,
    wrapperDisplayName: "UserIsAuthenticated",
    redirectAction: routerActions.replace
  });

export const userIsAuthenticated =
  makeUserIsAuthenticated<Record<string, unknown>>();
```

SubServiceOverview.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { userIsAuthenticated } from "libs/reduxAuth";
import services from "routes/services";

const ServiceOverview: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {services.map(service => (
          <li key={service.name}>
            <Link to={`/services/${service.name}`}>{service.name}</Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default userIsAuthenticated(ServiceOverview);
```

The error is thrown from this file. If I pass the SubServiceOverview in the **component** prop then the error goes away.

Routes.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { Login } from "containers";
import ServiceOverview from "containers/views/ServiceOverview";
import SubServiceOverview from "containers/views/SubServiceOverview";

const Routes: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <Redirect to="/services" />
      </Route>
      <Route component={Login} path="/login" /> //Login is also wrapped but doesn't throw error
      <Route exact component={ServiceOverview} path="/services" />
      <Route path="/services/:subService">
        <SubServiceOverview /> //this is the line that shows the error
      </Route>
    </>
  );
};

export default Routes;
```

Comment: Could you provide the line which is causing the error, maybe more information from console?

Comment: @dragomirik The <SubServiceOverview /> in Routes.tsx is throwing the error. It's showing a red underline on it and the only error message is the one I posted above.

Comment: If you unwrap the tree with errors in console, there will be more information. Anyway, try to replace the line with 
<SubServiceOverview redirect={null} redirectPath={null} isAuthenticated={null} isAuthenticating={null} />

And say if anything changed

Comment: @dragomirik I have not run the full code cause it's already showing red underline in the VS Code, hence no console error. But I have put ```<SubServiceOverview redirect={null} redirectPath="" isAuthenticated={false} isAuthenticating={false} />.```

The redirect props shows this: ```Type 'null' is not assignable to type '(...args: any[]) => Action'```

Comment: More error description on the redirect prop.

```The expected type comes from property 'redirect' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<Record<string, unknown> & InjectedAuthRouterProps<(...args: any[]) => Action>, any, any>> & Readonly<...> & Readonly<...>'```

Comment: Updating the code with

    `<SubServiceOverview redirect={[]} redirectPath="" isAuthenticated={false} isAuthenticating={false} />`

could resolve the problem, but it is not the way how it should work. Seems, you have to add relevant props. In this case try to reread the documentation.

Comment: @dragomirik That's the issue. I have seen some examples in JS. It doesn't cause any issue in JS. I also didn't have to pass any of these props in the resulting component. It would be great if there were enough TS examples. You might want to look into this example: https://github.com/mjrussell/redux-auth-wrapper/blob/master/examples/react-router-4/components/App.js